# Why do gnome apps ignore parts of gtk 3 themes?

Tags: css, linux, gtk, gtk3, gnome

I am extremely new to making gtk 3 themes, and I have created a theme that is working with any app that is using titlebars, but any gnome app (such as shotwell, or rhythmbox) is ignoring the theme completely. I have determined it is due to the gnome apps using header-bars rather than title bars, but the header-bars will not using background-color or any other css attribute other than background-image. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Because gnome apps partly use default system user interface, which maybe different from gtk3, you need to change settings both in apps (if any) and in the system - gnome settings. It depends from app to app.

Comment: what would I change to achieve the desired affects? Would I just need to add more headers that I'm unaware of in gtk.css theme files, or are there other files that I will need to alter?

Comment: Please, look through this topic: https://askubuntu.com/questions/78088/can-i-apply-a-different-gtk3-theme-from-the-main-one-to-an-individual-applicatio

Comment: Sorry for the much later response, but I did look through the post you provided, and they seemed to give solutions on an app by app basis which involved making specialized launchers for each desired application. I need all the gnome apps to use my theme without the need for the custom launcher. I know this is possible as other themes I have tinkered with in the past are capable of making the gnome apps conform to the theme.